# How to check if entered input has exactly 10 characters using arrays?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          int[] studentNumber = new int[10];

        string firstname, lastname;
        int i, unit;
        double grade, gwa;

        Console.Write("enter first name: ");
        firstname = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("enter last name: ");
        lastname = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("enter student number: ");

        if (studentNumber.Length != 10)
        {
            Console.Write("student number must be 10 characters!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        MessageBox.Show(firstname + " " + lastname + "\n" + studentNumber, "Mapua");

    }
}
}
```

How can I check if the user entered exactly 10 characters? And if the user did, how would I call that to my message box method? How could I show that in the output? Thank you!

Comment: Put your code here instead of posting as an image.

Comment: Its not instagram, How hard it could be to just copy, paste and indent?

Comment: I'm sorry, took me a while to figure out the indention

Comment: You are doing everything wrong, In winForm application, you can't use `Console.Readline`, you need to put textBoxes on your winForm for taking input from the user.

Comment: @M Adeel Khalid, you could say the same thing without beeing so rude.

Comment: @M Adeel Khalid, what I mean is that in this console application, you would call the message box method by enabling the System.Windows.Forms; my problem is, how would I display the inputted value for the student number in the message box? Considering that the inputted value should not exceed nor fall short of 10 characters max?

Answer (score 0):

You can just check with,

```
if(studentNumber.Length != 10)
{
    Console.Write("Student number must be 10 characters");       
}
```

And you cannot use messageBox in a console application, change it to windows form.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to enter a student number, and the output for the message box says System.Int32[]

Comment: @AJGayeta Well, you have to prompt the user for that information, but that was not your question...

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get the student number from the user, forcing them to enter 10 digits, and adding each valid character to your studentNumber array. The code basically does this:

1. Prompt the user to input the student number
2. While they have input less than 10 numbers:
3. Read the next key entered by the user
4. If the key entered **is not** a number (which we can determine by ensuring that the character is not less than `0` or greater than `9`), then subtract one from the cursor postion (making them re-enter the number), write a blank space over their entry, and back up the cursor position again (so it looks like their input was rejected, which it was).
5. If the key **is** a number, add it to our array and increment a counter so we know when they've entered 10 numbers:

Here's the sample code:

```
int[]studentNumber = new int[10];

Console.Write("enter student number: ");

int numbersEntered = 0;

while (numbersEntered < 10)
{
    var input = Console.ReadKey();

    // If the input is not a number, then reject their input by
    // backing up one character, writing a blank space over their
    // entry, and then back up again so we can get the next key.
    if (input.KeyChar < '0' || input.KeyChar > '9')
    {
        Console.CursorLeft -= 1;
        Console.Write(" ");
        Console.CursorLeft -= 1;
        continue;
    }

    studentNumber[numbersEntered] = int.Parse(input.KeyChar.ToString());
    numbersEntered++;
}
```

At the end of this loop, the `studentNumber` array will contain the 10 numbers entered by the user.